# Trying to use FreeSerif as a maths font -- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, luatex

Always in search of the ideal font combination unicorn, I thought I'd try the [GNU Free UCS Outline Fonts](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/freefont/) (FreeSerif, FreeSans, and FreeMono). I seem to have fallen at the first hurdle:

```
\documentclass[final]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{FreeSerif}
\begin{document}
\[x+y=\sqrt{z}\]
\end{document}
```

Both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX (`.otf` format fonts with TexLive, Windows 7) give me this:

[image: formatted output]

What am I missing?

Comment: **This is not an answer** but to help, here is using *XeTeX* http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/9996/shutterseleo006.png and here using *LuaLaTeX* http://img267.imageshack.us/img267/7355/shutterseleo007.png on my Lubuntu 11.10 with TexLive2011.

Comment: @Sigur Is that using the .otf version? (I'm on Windows 7)

Comment: Hum, sorry. I checked it now and I have those fonts in `.ttf` format. But I don't know if TeXLive uses them.

Comment: You can't use FreeSerif as a math font because it lacks a MATH table. Both XITS Math and TG Termes Math have the table and are based, like FreeSerif, on Times.

Comment: In Classic TeX (and apparently a fallback in xetex) the thickness of the rule in `\sqrt` is given by the _height_ of the sqrtsign character, so TeX fonts have a sqrtsign with large depth making tex math fonts unusable in other systems. The math table can specify this without needing to corrupt the glyph positioning.

Comment: @egreg: Would you like to make that an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use every OpenType font as a math font for `unicode-math`. At least a `MATH` table in the font is necessary, along with a `math` script. Although some of the basic setups can be performed, as it is shown by the italic letters in the formula, some important parameters for math typesetting are missing.

In your case the big problem is with the radical: as David Carlisle remarks, TeX uses for the thickness of the bar over the radicand the *height* of the radical symbol; however XeTeX and LuaTeX know how to use a different parameter from the MATH table, so the problem doesn't appear.<sup>1</sup>

A real math font must have also other information for the correct kerning of math characters in formulas. See the documentation of `mathspec` for more details and, probably, many more glyphs than FreeSerif has.

If your text font is FreeSerif, then a good choice for the math font can be either XITS Math or TG Termes Math, both based on Times.

<sub>1 Unfortunately, due to a bug in the current version of LuaTeX, the big black blob can appear also if the math font has the correct parameters in the `MATH` table.</sub>

Comment: About your note, the respective LuaTeX bug affects only `TFM` fonts, OpenType fonts with `MATH` table are not affected.